# CustomResource Spec value returning null

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources

Hi I have created following CustomResourceDefinition - crd.yaml

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: test.demo.k8s.com
  namespace: testns
spec:
  group: demo.k8s.com
  versions:
    - name: v1
      served: true
      storage: true
  scope: Namespaced
  names:
    plural: testpod
    singular: testpod
    kind: testpod
```

The corresponding resource is as below - cr.yaml

```
kind: testpod
metadata:
  name: testpodcr
  namespace: testns
spec:
  containers:
  - name: testname
    image: test/img:v5.16
    env:
    - name: TESTING_ON
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: kubernetes-config
          key: type
    volumeMounts:
    - name: testvol
      mountPath: "/test/vol"
      readOnly: true
```

When i use client-go program to fetch the spec value of cr object 'testpodcr' The value comes as null.

```
func (c *TestConfigclient) AddNewPodForCR(obj *TestPodConfig) *v1.Pod {
    log.Println("logging obj \n", obj.Name) // Prints the name as testpodcr
    log.Println("Spec value: \n", obj.Spec) //Prints null

    dep := &v1.Pod{
        ObjectMeta: meta_v1.ObjectMeta{
            //Labels: labels,
            GenerateName: "test-pod-",
        },
        Spec: obj.Spec,
    }

    return dep
}
```

Can anyone please help in figuring this out why the spec value is resulting to null

Comment: do you see your object in the cluster using kubectl?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error with Your `crd.yaml` file. I am getting the following error:

```
$ kubectl apply -f crd.yaml 
The CustomResourceDefinition "test.demo.k8s.com" is invalid: metadata.name: Invalid value: "test.demo.k8s.com": must be spec.names.plural+"."+spec.group
```

In Your configuration the `name: test.demo.k8s.com` does not match `plurar: testpod` found in `spec.names`.

I modified Your `crd.yaml` and now it works:

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: testpods.demo.k8s.com
  namespace: testns
spec:
  group: demo.k8s.com
  versions:
    - name: v1
      served: true
      storage: true
  scope: Namespaced
  names:
    plural: testpods
    singular: testpod
    kind: Testpod
```

```
$ kubectl apply -f crd.yaml 
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/testpods.demo.k8s.com created
```

After that Your `cr.yaml` also had to be fixed:

```
apiVersion: "demo.k8s.com/v1"
kind: Testpod
metadata:
  name: testpodcr
  namespace: testns
spec:
  containers:
  - name: testname
    image: test/img:v5.16
    env:
    - name: TESTING_ON
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: kubernetes-config
          key: type
    volumeMounts:
    - name: testvol
      mountPath: "/test/vol"
      readOnly: true
```

After that I created `namespace` `testns` and finally created `Testpod` object successfully:

```
$ kubectl create namespace testns
namespace/testns created
$ kubectl apply -f cr.yaml 
testpod.demo.k8s.com/testpodcr created
```